# Make SharePoint a pure WebDAV-server or avoid "We opened this workbook read-only from the server"

Tags: excel, webdav, http-headers

Don't stop reading - this is not the old "How can I stop Office opening my documents read-only from SharePoint"-question.

Here's the background:
We use SharePoint (2013 as a matter of fact, but I think this applies to 2016 and 2019 as well) to store dynamically generated Excel-documents.
We don't use any collaboration features, and the users are not even aware of that the files are stored in a SharePoint document library.

When the user clicks a link on our webpage, the following happens:

- An Excel document is generated and stored in the document library
- A JavaScript on the webpage opens the document just generated, using 
  the Office URI scheme, like so:

```
var uriSchemePrefix = "ms-excel:ofe|u|";
window.open(uriSchemePrefix + url, "_parent");

(where url above is the URL to the Excel document, "ofe" means 'Edit document')
```

This works in all major browsers. However, doing it this way, the document opens readonly in Excel, with the dreaded "We opened this workbook read-only from the server" warning bar. Not a great user experience, the document should just open in edit mode.

I know that this can be done, since opening an Excel document from a "plain" WebDAV-server (non-SharePoint) works (opens in edit mode).
For instance, if you go to https://webdavserver.net/ and drop an Excel-file there, you can edit the document directly, without the warning and without having to click "Edit workbook".

So, I used Fiddler to try to figure out what makes Excel realize that a SharePoint document library is not just a WebDAV server. Not a very scientific way of doing it, and something of a hack, but I come to the conclusion that be removing the following HTTP response headers in the response to the request the browser and Excel makes to open the document, I could (almost) reach my goal:

- MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices
- DocumentManagementServer

I do this using URL Rewrite (DocumentManagementServer) and with this in web.config:

```
<customHeaders>
          <remove name="MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices" />
</customHeaders>
```

I have to remove both, it is not enough with one of them.

Everything works great in IE, Edge, Chrome and Firefox on Windows.
But, on Mac, it doesn't work at all. It turns out that removing the MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices breaks something, so Excel can't open the file (gives a generic error, which I don't have access to right now). Strangely, it opens the file fine the first time, but fails subquent times.

But again, this can be done, since the experiment with https://webdavserver.net/ works on Mac also. 
It is just that I can't figure out which HTTP response headers to remove. There are so many, and if I remove the wrong headers, Excel crashes. Also, it might be that I have to remove a combination of headers, and the number of combinations is massive.

So, does anyone know how to do this? In other words, I guess, what HTTP response headers make Excel realize that it communicates with SharePoint and not just a plain WebDAV-server?